# Force org-babel-load-file to execute every time emacs is loaded

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel

I have this code in the init.el file:

> (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "myinit.org"
>   user-emacs-directory))

Which used to generate a myinit.el file every time I start emacs.
I would sometimes change the main myinit.org file, load a new emacs and check the effect of the change.

After updating org I noticed the myinit.el is not loaded with new changes in myinit.org anymore and I have to delete the (myinit.el) file then start emacs to force loading it.

Is there a way to always load a new myinit.el file when starting an emacs instance? Is this the right way to do it? why did the original behavior change after I updated org?

Comment: What version of Org mode did you have before the upgrade? What version do you have now? If you downgrade to the previous version does the problem go away?

Comment: I have 9.3 elpa. I honestly don't remember the last one I had.